# How to change the range of questions appearing in my feed in Stack Exchange iphone app?

Tags: support, ios-app

I am using Stack Exchange latest iOS app and below is what my default screen looks like when I open the app:

[image]

I just would like to see questions only from Stack Overflow.com and salesforce.stackexchange.com but right now it shows questions from all other network sites which I am not interested. So how do I change this behaviour?

Apologies if this is a very basic question. I tried googling but did not have any success.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this has been asked already but I'm mobile so I can't find it. :(

Comment: @Catija, Thanks but looks like there is no answer. so what do you recommend?

Comment: @javanoob nothing we can do except upvote the original request and trying to improve it by edits, which I just did.